# Symfony form builder - how to put form title in h2 selector?

Tags: symfony, twig, formbuilder

I want my form title to be displayed in h2 selector. I did something like that but it throws me an error "exception: "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: -1").""

```
 // how should I change THIS part? To change only the main form title/label?
 // I made it work somehow but then it changes all labels... Is there some 
 // selector which allows to style MAIN title of the form?
{% block form_label %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <h2>{{ form_label(form) }}</h2>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

I've heard that I shouldn't put it in my project file in h2 selector just in form template. It's cleaner and even though documentation doesn't forbide that I was encouraged to do it another way and that's how I want to try it.

```
{% form_theme form 'Forms/base_form.html.twig' %}
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_label(form, 'Project title', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'main-form-label'} }) }} 
  // so as I shouldn't put all that line in <h2> can I somehow do it in template between  {% block form_label %} ?

    {{ form_row(form.title, {'label': 'My title'}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.isComplete, {'label': 'Dropdown'}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.comment, {'label': 'Comment'}) }}
    {{ form_row(form.submit, {'label': 'Submit'}) }}


{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Also... Whats the difference/what should I use - `{% block form_label %}` or `{%- block form_label -%}`

My whole template:

```
{% block form_label %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <h2>{{ form_label(form) }}</h2>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}

{% block form_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_row %}

{% block submit_row %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="col-12">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock submit_row %}

{% block text_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <div class="col-12">
            <div>
                {{ form_label(form) }}
            </div>
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </div>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock text_widget %}

{% block choice_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        <span>
            {{ form_label(form) }}

            {% if expanded %}
                {{ block('choice_widget_expanded') }}
            {% else %}
                {{ block('choice_widget_collapsed') }}
            {% endif %}
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </span>
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget %}
```

Comment: Hi, have you tried to override your template ? following https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html
What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @S.Bureau yup, I just posted the whole template I did.

Comment: I assume that your template is already extending an other... Could you try this `{% block form_label -%}<h2>{{- parent() -}}</h2>{%- endblock form_label %}`

Comment: Apparently, I am not extending another one :P 400, exception: "Calling "parent" on a template that does not extend nor "use" another template is forbidden."

Comment: Oups, sorry for that bah assumption :p Well, you may try to add the following line at the beginning of your template : `{% use "form_div_layout.html.twig" %}` This file is the basic layout included with symfony/twig vendor so you should find it without problem. Other solution is to override the `{%- block form_label -%}` from this file.

Comment: Hum, I just read your update to the first code block... I hadn't understood that you wanted only the first label in <h2> tag. Could you share how you have defined this title in your FormType ?

Comment: Doesn't work, stil gives me "An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: -1").". Is it even possible to style ONLY the main title of the form? I feel like the whole block form_label is about all labels, those used in widgets as well.

Comment: Yes, I added another comment, I understood what you wanted after reading your update to the OP -__-' (sorry...). Could you share how you define the label you want to display in your FormType ?

Comment: I didn't see any Type that would allow me to style form title independently so... I didn't add it there. It's just thrown like that in my twig `{{ form_label(form, 'Project title', { 'label_attr': {'class': 'main-form-label'} }) }} `
I think I'm just  making it harder than it should be. I'll just put it between h2 in my file and avoid making template. Its just one marker I need to add for every form :)

Comment: I don't know how you define your "Main title" in your FormType, but if you do so, you can pass an attribute from your FormType to your form template. In your template, you check the presence of that attribute, if so, you put your label between <h2> tags, if not, you simply do as you do it anywhere else.

Comment: What kind of attribute should that be? Class would be fine? You mean sth like that `->add('title',TextType::class, [ 'attr' => ['class' => 'mainTitle']])` - in form builder and in my template : `{%- block form_label -%}
    {% if form.parent class 'mainTitle' %}
        <h2>{{ form_label(form) }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
{%- endblock form_label -%}` ?

Comment: Yes, class would be fine :) (in label_attr attribute inside your FormType to be cleaner)

Comment: How should I check if this element has class in template? Form builder doesn't work with hasClass()

Comment: Give me one minute to make a whole answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you get stuck somewhere ;)
We use to do it this way (when we want custom rendering).

First, we extend the FormType :

```
namespace App\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class FormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefault('main_title', false);
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('main_title', 'boolean');
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars['main_title'] = $options['main_title'];
    }
}
```

Think to register you extension in Symfony !

Then you can use it in your form builder this way :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add(
        'myField',
        TextType::class,
        array(
            'main_title' => true
        ));
}
```

Finally, in your template :

```
{% block form_row -%}
{% spaceless %}

    {% if main_title %}
        <h2>{{ form_label(form) }}</h2>
    {% else %}
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {% endif %}

{% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock form_row %}
```

Feel free to override that block with your needs ;-)

Comment: Woah! Now, I think that my example is really to small to use it just for h2 but it gives so much more space to adjust everything if making some really dope form! Thanks Man! Custom form types appear to be a bit less of a black magic ;)

Comment: Very glad to read that ! Symfony is magic !!! :D    
At work, we use Extensions a lot to fit our needs ;-)